# C++ set lower_bound() iterator

Tags: c++

I want to find the greatest element in a std::set in C++ strictly less than a given element. Some questions suggest finding lower_bound iterator and decrementing it i.e.

```
set<int> st;
// Add elements
int x;
// calculate x
auto it = st.lower_bound(x);
if(it != st.begin()) {
    it--;
}
```

[Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) is unclear as to what type of iterator does lower_bound return (e.g Forward, Bidirectional) so how do we know decrementing this iterator is valid ? Also can we estimate the complexity of decrementing std::set iterator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `set::lower_bound` on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/lower_bound/), under "Return value":

> Member types `iterator` and `const_iterator` are [bidirectional iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/BidirectionalIterator) types pointing to elements.

so you'll always be able to decrement the iterator (after your `begin` check, of course).

The complexity of decrementing an iterator will always be (amortized) constant. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11780212/1848578).

Comment: Just to be correct you might want to add that it is amortized constant.

Answer (score 1):

The return types of [std::set::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) are `std::set::iterator` or `std::set::const_iterator`, which are [member types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set#Member_types) of `std::set`, they're both constant [bidirectional iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator).