# Time complexity of std::set, std::multiset, std::map and std::multimap iterator increment in C++ standard library

Tags: c++, stl

It's well known, that next element search complexity in binary tree is O(log(N)). But whether tree nodes are also double linked list nodes, complexity would be O(1).

So, the question is: are std::set nodes also double linked list nodes by C++ standard, or it depends on realization? In other worlds, has `it++` operation complexity `O(log(N)` or `O(1)`, where N is the number of set elements?

I didn't find corresponding subsection or paragraph in section "Iterators library" of https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf
Maybe I searched badly.

Comment: Only about _iterator_ _increment_ complexity

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11779859/10871073) a duplicate? The answers imply (one even states) that an individual increment should be in amortized constant time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [[iterator.requirements.general] p13](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#13):

> All the categories of iterators require only those functions that are realizable for a given category in constant time (amortized).
> Therefore, requirement tables and concept definitions for the iterators do not specify complexity.

This paragraph isn't found in the C++03 standard (which you've linked); it has been added in C++11.

`std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map`, and `std::multimap` provide [*BidirectionalIterator*](https://eel.is/c++draft/bidirectional.iterators#def:Cpp17BidirectionalIterator)s, so they support `++i`, and `--i` for an iterator `i`, and this must have amortized constant complexity.

Also, the C++ standard doesn't require that `std::set` is implemented as a balanced binary tree where nodes have a link to their parent, but the requirements imposed on it *strongly* suggest such an implementation. A simple doubly linked list couldn't satisfy all the complexity requirements.

#### See Also

- [What's the time complexity of iterating through a std::set/std::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11779859/5740428) (also applies to `std::multiset` and `std::multimap`)
- [What are the complexity guarantees of the standard containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/181693/5740428)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually "searched badly". I hoped, that complexity is simply constant, not _amortized_.

Comment: @MishaT A [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) also satisfies the requirements in a straightforward way (and does have strictly constant iterator increment).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI yeah, I mean a tree structure where there are at least links that would allow forward and backward navigation. I've improved the wording to make things more clear.